# Access complex If Statement

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba

Here's some background - i'm creating an access form that allows users in a call centre to select options from several combo and tickboxes and it generates the relevant call script into a textbox based on their selections.

I'm in the process of writing the VBA code that adds together various paragraphs of pre-determined text into a textbox based on the options selected. I've created a string for each of these paragraphs of text in VBA and i'm trying to write the IF statements to put them together, however there will eventually be around 50 different option variations and i'm struggling to find a way around this without writing 50 different If/ElseIf statements :|

Below is a snippet of what I've come up with so far, with the only difference in the ElseIf being that [FullRefund] is False which replaces the 'FullRef' string with 'OPLim' in the textbox value

```
If [PreAuthType] = "Out Patient" _
  And [FullRefund] = True _
  And [ExcessLimit] > 0 _
  And [Text58] < 93 _
  And [OpenRef] = False _
  And [TxtReq] = False _
  And [ClaimsBonus] = True Then
     Me.GenScript.Value = Stan & FullRef & Excess & Renewal & OpenRef & NoText & BonusTxt
ElseIf [PreAuthType] = "Out Patient" _
  And [FullRefund] = False _
  And [ExcessLimit] > 0 _
  And [Text58] < 93 _
  And [OpenRef] = False _
  And [TxtReq] = False _
  And [ClaimsBonus] = True Then
     Me.GenScript.Value = Stan & OPLim & Excess & Renewal & OpenRef & NoText & BonusTxt
End If
```

Any help or guidance you can offer to at least get me going would be amazing :)

Comment: Would have to know all 50 variations to advise. As you said, only variation is with FullRefund and the only change in the concatenation is FullRef vs. OPLim. What is a 'call script'? I work in a call center and cannot imagine what this is for.

Comment: The advisors follow very specific script on calls but the content can vary depending on who they're talking to/what they're advising. At the moment they have a large text document they have to read through and pick out certain paragraphs if it meets the criteria of the call, however i'd like to be able to just give them the paragraphs they need to read out depending on the values they've input on the form. I wouldn't be able to note all of the variables, but to give you an idea; each of the values in my first example could be either true/false and would need a different bit of script for each.

Comment: Are all of the combinations based on these same 7 criteria?

Comment: There are around 10 fields the advisors have to fill out. If, for example, the value of [Text58] is less than 93 then the script would need to contain the 'Renewal' string of text, if it's greater than 93 then 'Renewal' should be omitted from the eventual script. On the most part there are 2 options for each field (most are True/False), each associated with specific paragraphs of text, where 'True' brings paragraph A into the call script and 'False' brings paragraph B.

Comment: Okay well don't worry about the code yet -- the first thing you need is a simple list of each criteria and all possible options.  (most are just true/false)...  **actually the first thing you need to do is rename `Text58`** ...unless that's the actual name of something! It's bad coding practice (and a pet peeve) and this is your last chance top easily rename things! :)

Comment: This is actually fairly simple, once you organize a list.  **(1)** What options are there for `PreAuthType` other than `Out Patient`?  **(2)** What options are there for `ExcessLimit` and `Text58`?  0-100?

Comment: My bad :) Okay, ignore all 10 fields and say we've only got 3: PreAuthType (4 values), Excess (Number), and OpenRef (true/false). if option A, B, or C of PreAuthType is selected then the 'Stan' and 'Excess' strings need to be returned, however if ExcessLimit is >0 then 'Excess' needs to also be included, and if OpenRef is True then 'OpenReferral' also needs to be included. Is there an easy way to structure that?

Comment: "easy" is a relative term.  Easier than what you were going to do?  Absolutely by far!  I'm going to start this as an answer even though its incomplete.  (Someone might complain!)  Once I get you started you should be able to take over...

Comment: After reading back the comment i hoped you wouldn't pick up on that! i'll change my wording from 'Easy' to 'Logical - but in no way straightforward!'. Thanks for your help, hopefully with a bit of direction i should be able to crack the rest myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, instead of writing a separate `IF` statement for every possible result, build the result step by step.  The very *purpose* of computer programs is to eliminate repetition, not to increase it.  There are a number of ways you could tackle this, but here's an example of the most basic because this is (believe it or not) an ***extremely* simple** set of logic comparisons.

This is already the majority of the coding that will be required...

```
Sub BuildScript()


    Dim scrOut As String 'a string to use to build the output

    scrOut = stan 'standard beginning for all results, I assume?

    If fullrefund Then  'if [full refund] is true then...
        scrOut = scrOut & FullRef  '...add this top the end of [scrOut]...
    Else
        scrOut = scrOut & opLim '...otherwise add this to [scrOut].
    End If

    If ExcessLimit > 0 Then
        scrOut = scrOut & excess
    Else
        scrOut = scrOut & "___something else if excessLimit <= 0___"
    End If

    If Text58 < 93 Then
        scrOut = scrOut & renewal
    Else
        scrOut = scrOut & "___something else if Text58 >= 93___"
    End If

    If openRef Then
        scrOut = scrOut & openRef
    Else
        scrOut = scrOut & "___something of openRef=false"
    End If

    If TxtReq Then
        scrOut = scrOut & " ___something if txtReq=true___"
    Else
        scrOut = scrOut & NoText
    End If

    If ClaimBonus Then
        scrOut = scrOut & BonusTxt
    Else
        scrOut = scrOut & "___something else if ClaimBonus=False___"
    End If

    MsgBox scrOut  'display a message box with the result
                   '(don't worry about what to do with it until later)
End Sub
```

---

### Edit:

Forgetting for a minute about the above code, I'll demonstrate your 3-option example:

> PreAuthType (4 values), Excess (Number), and OpenRef (true/false). if option A, B, or C of PreAuthType is selected then the 'Stan' and 'Excess' strings need to be returned, however if ExcessLimit is >0 then 'Excess' needs to also be included, and if OpenRef is True then 'OpenReferral' also needs to be included.

```
PreAuthType:    one of:  A, B, C, D
Excess:         numeric value from ___ to ___
OpenRef:        TRUE or FALSE only


Select Case PreAuthType
    Case A, B, C
        scrOut = Stan & Excess
    Case D
         '(does this option get anything specific?)
End Select

If Excess > 0 then
    scrOut = scrOut & "The Excess is $" & Excess
end if

If OpenRef the
    scrOut = scrOut & "Referral " & OpenReferral & " needs to be blah blah."
End If
```

Note that in the `IF` statements above:

```
If OpenRef then...
```

is exactly the same as writing:

```
If OpenRef = True then...
```

Similarly, this:

```
If Not OpenRef then...
```

is identical to this:

```
If OpenRef = False then...
```

---

### More Information:

- [Using If...Then...Else Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee440532(v=office.12).aspx)

  (look at a criteria and choose between 2 results.)
- [VBA for Beginners: VBA Case Function in a Nutshell](http://www.onlinepclearning.com/vba-beginners-vba-case-function-nutshell/)  ("Select..Case")

  (look at a criteria and choose between *many* results)
- [VBA 'Like' Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/like-operator)

  (compare 'close matches', ie: if it starts with `A` then do this)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. I should be able to build the rest in from here. Thanks for your direction!

Comment: It seems like most of these are standalone criteria, correct?  Like, the value of PreAuthType doesn't affect whether `ExcessLimit` is included, correct?  If it's more complicated than I'm understanding, then there is a better way to do this.  But if each individual criteria builds an individual section of the Callscript then this is fairly straightforward.

Comment: I've been working on this all day (on a Sunday, i know!) and this is the bit I've been dreading. Apologies, in my last comment i created a makeshift example using just 3 variables to simplify things. Say (in this example) that if PreAuthType is option B or C then OpenRef should be disregarded but ExcessLimit isn't affected either way.

Comment: I may be coming across as impatient but I don't mean to...  Get this: Sunday and I do this for FUN.  :-)  It's hard to explain at first because there is a learning curve for sure, but that's a great plan of yours to start with a couple criteria, get them doing what they are supposed to do, and add one at a time from there....

Comment: ...so yeah, these all sound pretty non-dependent of each other.  Before you get too far into this, we need to make sure it's setup so you can test it along the way,  **IDEALLY** you will make a change, test it against a bunch of data, make sure it's doing what it's supposed to, **save**, and then make the next change.  Don't try to write the whole thing at once without testing frequently, because it can be a real bitch trying to figure out where the mistake was from 8 hours before.

Comment: I've made that mistake before! Using your suggestions I can see now how to make this work...however its too late in the day now to even have a go at it. This is a job for tomorrow! Thanks again mate and i'll come back with an update. - to answer your question below though - ExcessLimit is either >0 or not, and RenewalCheck (the artist previously known as Text58) is either <93 or >=93, so not much variance there. The only real variable is PreAuthType, which has an affect on most of the script, however i can prepare the smaller variables first and call them last depending on PreAuthType,

Comment: I'd like to know more about `ExcessLimit` and `Text58`.   For example: With `Texr58`, obviously the range "<93" is significant.  Are there other cutoffs?  ie., 93-95, 96-123, does zero mean something important?  can it be less than zero... etc etc etc?  Brainstorm for all possibilities of both.  You want to have this planned out ahead of time.  For example, if certain things need to be handled differently if `Text58` is less than 10, then you'll need to go back and change everywhere you said `<93` , since `<10` is included in `<93`..  Clear as mud?

Comment: Alright, that sounds good.  Next step when you come back to it, maybe take a sheet of paper and a pencil and list out all "significant" options for each of your criteria before getting too deep into the coding.  I actually *enjoy* helping with this kind of stuff (and believe in Karma!) so do't hesitate to ask.